# what's the difference between MVVM and Prism v2

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, prism-2

what's the difference between MVVM and prism v2 design pattern to develop SL and WPF applications?

Answer (score 8):

Prism is not a design pattern, but a Library of different components; some of them can help you implementing the MVVM-pattern, for example with Commanding.

Comment: Hello
thank you gammelgul,

composite application is a design pattern?
so what's the difference between the composite application guidance for SL and WPF and the MVVM?

thank u

Answer (score 1):

Prism is much more than MVVM, it provides a lot of features/base classes out of the box which you will have to implement yourself in your custom MVVM implementation; Prism provides a standard way of solving various problems/scenarios encountered in SL or WPF application (EventAggregator, Navigation framework, commanding etc.).

Prism is more suitable for large-scale applications which will be maintained/evolved for years by a lot of developers.

MVVM is better suited for light-weight applications which needs to be developed once and quickly. Although if you want flexibility you can develop your own MVVM framework or use available ones(like MVVM light etc.).

Also have a look at this question which I had asked about Prism -

[Custom MVVM implementation Vs. PRISM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251821/custom-mvvm-implementation-vs-prism)